# Debug code on machine without installing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, remote-debugging

I have one test machine that my program needs to run on that machine. It fails to run but I don't know the reason.

I want to debug the code on that machine to check the issue without installing Visual Studio 2012 on that machine. I have the source code of the program. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the remote debugging tools, go to your start menu, find your visual studio and expand it, find Visual Studio Tools and then remote debugging folder.

When you have this copy the x86 or x64 folder over to the machine you want to debug on and run the application or web page and msvsmon.exe.

Then on your machine from the debugging menu attach to process, and then target the machine that you want to run against.

Then look for the process you want to debug

Comment: Can you add a word about prerequisites, like access rights or VS version ? Will it work with Express, Community etc..?

Comment: @TaW worked with VS 2015 Community. I had to run msvsmon with administrator privileges (I guess it depends on the user of the target process, which in this case had high privileges).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) and debug the remote code on your machine as you have the source code. You can also write exception logs in remote application to know what error has occurred at what place in your code. For remote debugging the see the detailed explanation about remote debugging as under from MSDN article.

[How to: Enable Remote Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/febz73k0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Visual Studio provides support for remote debugging, that is, the ability to debug an .exe on another computer connected to your network. The Use remote machine property on the Debug page of the Project Designer enables remote debugging of an .exe. When this option is selected, you must specify the name of the machine on which the .exe will run. The location of the .exe on the remote machine must match the value of the Make exe path property, which is on the Compile page of the Project Designer.
In order to debug on a remote machine, the following conditions must be met:

- The remote machine must have debugger components installed.
- The user of the local machine needs to be in the Debugger Users group on the remote machine.
- The .exe must be in a shareable directory on the remote machine.
  For more information, [see Remote Debugging Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx).

**To enable remote debugging**

1. Make sure that the remote machine is properly configured for remote 2. debugging. For more information, [see Remote Debugging Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx).
2. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu click Properties.
3. Click the Debug tab.
4. Select the Use remote machine check box.
5. In the Use remote machine field, enter the name of the remote machine, using the format \domain\machinename.

Comment: Can you add a word about prerequisites, like access rights or VS version ? Will it work with Express, Community etc..?

Answer (score 0):

I would check remote debugging. You can find information about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).